# Install gulp ERR (linux)

Tags: linux, gulp

При попытке установить gulp локальной в папку с проектом выдает ERR:

```
ForceLink-PC gulp # npm i -D gulp
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "-D" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/forcelink/Developer/gulp/npm-debug.log
```

Gulp успешно установлен глобально, а локально почему-то не хочет.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Файл npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'i', '-D', 'gulp' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v4.2.6
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData gulp
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData gulp
9 silly mapToRegistry name gulp
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
13 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
14 verbose request no auth needed
15 info attempt registry request try #1 at 10:49:08
16 verbose request id 892095c2faaccb1d
17 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
18 http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
19 verbose headers { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
19 verbose headers   server: 'UploadServer',
19 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
19 verbose headers   'last-modified': 'Thu, 22 Mar 2018 16:06:34 GMT',
19 verbose headers   etag: '"5ab3d48a-1e29a"',
19 verbose headers   'x-npm-region': 'EU-East',
19 verbose headers   'content-encoding': 'gzip',
19 verbose headers   'content-length': '18927',
19 verbose headers   'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
19 verbose headers   date: 'Sun, 08 Apr 2018 07:49:08 GMT',
19 verbose headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
19 verbose headers   age: '12016',
19 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
19 verbose headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-hhn1524-HHN',
19 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
19 verbose headers   'x-cache-hits': '16',
19 verbose headers   'x-timer': 'S1523173749.972729,VS0,VE0',
19 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' }
20 silly get cb [ 200,
20 silly get   { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
20 silly get     server: 'UploadServer',
20 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
20 silly get     'last-modified': 'Thu, 22 Mar 2018 16:06:34 GMT',
20 silly get     etag: '"5ab3d48a-1e29a"',
20 silly get     'x-npm-region': 'EU-East',
20 silly get     'content-encoding': 'gzip',
20 silly get     'content-length': '18927',
20 silly get     'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
20 silly get     date: 'Sun, 08 Apr 2018 07:49:08 GMT',
20 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
20 silly get     age: '12016',
20 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
20 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-hhn1524-HHN',
20 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
20 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '16',
20 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1523173749.972729,VS0,VE0',
20 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' } ]
21 verbose get saving gulp to /home/forcelink/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/gulp/.cache.json
22 verbose makeDirectory /home/forcelink/.npm creation not in flight; initializing
23 silly makeDirectory /home/forcelink/.npm uid: 1000 gid: 1000
24 silly install normalizeTree
25 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
26 silly loadIdealTree Starting
27 silly install loadIdealTree
28 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
29 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
30 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
31 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
32 silly install loadShrinkwrap
33 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
34 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
35 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
36 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
37 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
38 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
39 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
40 silly install printInstalled
41 verbose stack Error: Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself
41 verbose stack     at checkSelf (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:40:14)
41 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
41 verbose stack     at LOOP (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
41 verbose stack     at chain (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
41 verbose stack     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:15:5
41 verbose stack     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:35
41 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
41 verbose stack     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:11
41 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
41 verbose stack     at asyncMap (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:51:8)
42 verbose cwd /home/forcelink/Developer/gulp
43 error Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
44 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "-D" "gulp"
45 error node v4.2.6
46 error npm  v3.5.2
47 error code ENOSELF
48 error Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself
49 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
49 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
50 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попытка установить "gulp в gulp"

```
Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself
(отказано в установке как зависимость к самому себе)
```

Вы выполняете установку в "неправильной" директории или имя **пакета совпадает с именем зависимости (пакета), не уникально** (например вы назвали свой проект/пакет/директорию - `gulp` и пытаетесь установить опять же `gulp` как зависимость)

Судя по логам `/home/forcelink/Developer/gulp/*` ваш проект/пакет называется `gulp`. Выберите уникальное имя пакета/проекта/директории, не совпадающее с именами устанавливаемых зависимостей.

например новый пакет `my-project`:

```
mkdir my-project
cd my-project
npm init --yes
npm i -D gulp
```